# Forma correcta de firmar un .pkg en mac?

Tags: macos, pkg, certificado-apple

Tengo un .pkg que he creado para distribuir el software de mi empresa, mas cuando lo bajan desde otras mac dice "No se puede abrir porque proviene de un desarrollador no identificado", el pkg esta firmado con un certificado valido del tipo **App Store Installer** con la herramienta [productsign](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productsign.1.html), el certificado aparece de manera correcta en la parte superior derecha del .pkg y es valido, abre sin ningun problema, excepto cuando lo bajan desde internet, hay alguna otra forma para firmarlo o evitar eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que hice fue cambiar el tipo de certificado a uno del tipo Developer ID Installer:

1. Entra en developer.apple.com/account, y da click en Certificates, IDs & Profiles.
2. En la barra lateral, selecciona OS X desde el menu, y bajo Certificates, selecciona ALL.
3. Click en el boton (+) en la parte superior derecha.
4. Selecciona Developer ID que esta bajo Production, y has click en Continue.
5. Selecciona el tipo de certificado —Developer ID Application o Developer ID Installer— y da  click en Continuar.
6. Sigue las instrucciones para crear un "certificate signing request (CSR)" utilizando Keychain Access, y da click a Continuar.
7. Click en Choose File.
8. Selecciona un archivo CSR (con una extension .certSigningRequest), y click en Choose.
9. Click en Continuar.
10. Click en descargar (Download).

> OJO: Solo el Team Agent puede crear ese tipo de certificado, si no
>   eres el Team Agent, aun siendo usuario Admin no podras crearlo,
>   comunicate con tu Team Agent y enviale tu archivo CSR para que pueda
>   generarte el certificado.

Una vez hecho esto, da doble click al certificado (previamente descargado) para agregarlo al Keychain Access y procedes a firmar tu .pkg con la herramienta productsign(1) de la siguiente manera (Terminal):
`productsign [options] --sign identity input-product-path output-product-path`

Ejemplo:

```
productsign --sign "Nombre de tu Certificado en Keychain Access" ruta-de-entrada-al-pkg ruta-de-salida-al-pkg
```